# In MediaWiki, perform an action on every page of a namespace through API or maintenance script

Tags: mediawiki

How to programmatically — through the API or through a maintenance script — do an action on every page from a specified namespace?

I would for example like to add every page of the main namespace into a specified category, for maintenance purpose.

Answer (score -1):

I've had to do this on a few occasions.

It looks like the way to do things now is through the [Pywikibot scripts](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aPywikibot/Scripts). These are tools written in Python for automating tasks on MediaWiki sites. Unlike most of the MediaWiki documentation, the PWB docs are actually pretty thorough.

When I last had to add some text to every page, I couldn't find a bot that worked with my private instance running on my intranet, since most bots were written to work with Wikipedia.

What I ended up doing was just generating a list of page URLs, and then fed them to a custom script that utilized [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) to automate a browser running on my machine. You can use Selenium from Java, Python, C#, and Ruby.

It's a pretty heavyweight approach though, since you actually have to be running a realtime browser to do the work.

Take a look at [Pywikibot](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aPywikibot).

Comment: Every « big framework » works with any MediaWiki installation. In addition of Pywikibot, you have for example have DotNetWikiBot.

I'm a little puzzled by your comment, as authentication is the same on Wikipedia and regular MediaWiki installations, so as long as there is no need for a custom SSO solution to login, it should works.

Comment: @Derekcson So my answer is not helpful because I mentioned a problem I had many years ago as an aside and explained a workaround? Pywikibot is my current recommendation.